# Javascript total price calclator?

Tags: javascript, calculator

yeah im having some trouble with this, it wont calculate the prices and i was hoping some one would could help me please

```js
function calculatePrice(myForm){

  //Get selected data  
  var elt = document.getElementById("tickets1");
  var tickets1 = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;
  
  var elt = document.getElementById("tickets2");
  var tickets2 = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;
  
  //convert data to integers
  tickets1 = parseInt(tickets1);
  tickets2 = parseInt(tickets2);
  
  //calculate total value  
  var total = tickets1 + tickets2;
  
  //print value to  PicExtPrice 
  document.getElementById("PicExtPrice").value=total;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/stylepage.css"> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../JS/prcecal.js">
 </script>
 </head>
 <center>
  <body>
   <fieldset>
   <div id="box_1">
   <center><h2>Order</h2></center>
    <form name="myForm">
     Email:
     <br>
     <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required />
     <br>
     <br>
     Date:
     <br>
     <input type="date" name="date" id="date" min="today" required />
     <br>
     <br>
     <div id="dropdowns">
     <SELECT NAME="Ticketsadults" onChange="calculatePrice()" id="tickets1">
     <OPTION value="0">0</OPTION>
     <OPTION value="20">1</OPTION>
     <OPTION value="40">2</OPTION>
     <OPTION value="60">3</OPTION>
     <OPTION value="80">4</OPTION>
     </SELECT>
     <br>
     <SELECT NAME="Ticketskids" onChange="calculatePrice()" id="tickets2" >
     <OPTION value="0">0</OPTION>
     <OPTION value="20">1</OPTION>
     <OPTION value="40">2</OPTION>
     <OPTION value="60">3</OPTION>
     <OPTION value="80">4</OPTION>
     </SELECT>
     </div>
     <br>
     <br>
     <br>
     <button type="button" onclick="calculatePrice()">Calculate</button>
     <INPUT type="text" id="PicExtPrice" Size=8>
     </form>
   </center>
  </div>
 </fieldset>
 </body>
</html>
```

Ive tried changing it around and stuff but it still wont calcualte the two select drop downs

Comment: The browser console is literally telling you the exact error.  You never defined the variables `tick1` or `tick2`.

Comment: Open the browsers debug window (F12).

Comment: Suman Lama, you are no help

Comment: Looks to me like the updated code is working.

Comment: Yeah its working on here but when on put it on notepad++ she dont work, not sure why

Comment: Notepad++ is just a text editor. As far as I'm aware, it won't run your code. Are you saying it doesn't work when you run the HTML file in your browser?

Comment: If you want, you can link a JSFiddle that has everything in your Notepad++ put into the HTML bit of the fiddle, and I'll see if there's something else going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put `parseInt(tick1)` and `parseInt(tick2)` instead of `parseInt(tickets1)` and `parseInt(tickets2)`.

Also, you put `tick1 + tick2` instead of `tickets1 + tickets2`.

Comment: Then what about the `parseInt` part?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Thanks, it's fixed now.